# JHipster: open a user file

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, jhipster

In my jhipster project i need create a new xlsx  file based on template. I put my template  file1.xlsx to target/classes/clientdoc.

When i first time generate a new xlsx file it 's ok. But second time i got NPE on the call "sheet.getRow(rowForTotalInfoNumber).getCell(n)". Then i just open in LibreCalc (on the Linux) target/classes/clientdoc/file1.xlsx and close without any manipulation with it. After that my project is restarted in console. 
I executed my project by calling  ./mvnw. After that  i can create  a new file again.

This is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientDocConfiguration {
    private final Logger log = 

   @Bean
   public FilelGenerator getFileGenerator() {
   return new FileGenerator();
}

   @Bean
   public XSSFWorkbook workbook() throws IOException {
       Resource xlsRes = new ClassPathResource("clientdocs/file.xlsx");
       InputStream xlsStream = xlsRes.getInputStream();
       XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsStream);
       return workbook;
  }
```

FileGenerator.java

```
@Component
public class FileGenerator { 
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;

    @Autowired
    public void setWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        this.workbook = workbook;
    }


    public byte[] generateDocument() throws IOException {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        sheet.getRow(rowForTotalInfoNumber).getCell(n).setCellValue("X");
    }
```

Comment: If you get `NPE` on the call `sheet.getRow(rowForTotalInfoNumber).getCell(n).setCellValue("X")` then either `sheet` is `null` or `sheet.getRow(rowForTotalInfoNumber)` returns null or `sheet.getRow(rowForTotalInfoNumber).getCell(n)` returns null. Try determining what of the three exactly is `null` in your case. We cannot since we don't know where `rowForTotalInfoNumber` and `n`are coming from.

Comment: But why first time  i could get cell ? I didn't change template file. And but why a strange manipulation with file (opening in LibreOffice) helped me?

Comment: This we cannot know because the code you are showing is not as complete that we could know this. It is not even clear how `generateDocument` gets called nor how `FileGenerator.workbook` gets set.

Comment: This is spring boot project, so workbook is injected by spring.  
and generateDocument() is called as 
byte[] data = fileGenerator.generateDocument();